# How to invoke snippets for python code in Eclipse with Aptana plugin?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana, code-snippets

I understand, that Eclipses Aptana plugin comes with some predefined templates like

```
def ${method}(${param}):${cursor}
```

How do I invoke them? The usual `CTRL+SPACE` doesn't seem to work.

**Edit**: I found out, that typing for example `def` and hitting `CTRL+SPACE` afterwords does not work. But Hitting `CTRL+SPACE` first would show me a drop down menu from which I can select `def` by scrolling. Also, it is possible to start typing inside the drop down menu to "navigate" to `def`. Is this the way it is meant to be?

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to invoke "autocomplete" for the definition of a function and you typed the `def` `CTRL+SPACE` does nothing.

But if you hit `CTRL+SPACE` and then type `def` you can select the snippet by hitting enter!

Works for every (python/aptana) snippet appearently.